# ASMX service sharing a single class instance

Tags: c#, iis, asmx

I have a webservice with a .asmx extension which points to a class in my web application. After adding some code to output a debug log on application startup, I can see a new debug log is being created every time a user visits the page.

I was hoping that I could configure this web service to only ever use a single instance.

Meaning, when the first user visits the site it creates an instance of my webservice, and then all requests after are routed through that same class, sharing the same state.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You want multiple instances of your web service. Otherwise, each inbound HTTP request would be blocked by any and every request in front of it. You can use static variables to store specific information - but be careful to minimize the use to just the data you want to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

Web sites are stateless in nature.  Meaning, each request is generally unrelated to any other request.

That said, you could set the log as a static variable in your global.asax file.  Be aware of threading issues.

Alternatively you might look at [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a number of problems.

First of all, the ASMX technology is all but obsolete, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used instead.

Next, yes, you can have multiple calls to the service share the same instance of your class. However, you'll have to prevent simultaneous access to this class unless it is thread safe. You should expect multiple service calls to call into the same class instance at the same time.

Finally, ASMX does not support singleton web services. The best you can do is to have multiple service calls all share the same object (carefully locked).

Comment: I'd use WCF if I could but I'm trying to make a system which is compatable with the old system.

Comment: Why would WCF not be compatible?

Comment: When you say WCF are you referring to the .SVC extension? Or something else?

Comment: WCF typically uses the .svc extension. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info for a good starting point.

Comment: The original project was written with ASMX. I initially tried getting things to work using the .SVC extension instead, but I found that the responses returned were framed differently. ASMX appears to use some sort of SOAP container, where as SVC does not. Truly though, there isn't much difference between SVC and ASMX in terms of implementation, and I imagine that switching to SVC at a later date when I have more time to figure these things out will be quite simple.

Comment: Please read the link I posted. You're quite far off. WCF is the replacement for ASMX. It completely replaces the functionality.